# Плагин Eclipse для получения UML диаграмм классов из существующего кода

Tags: uml, eclipse, java

Товарищи, какие есть плагины Eclipse для reverse engineering существующего кода? Для Нетбинса нашел с легкостью, а с Эклипсом мучаюсь уже полтора часа. Один момент - должен быть опен-сорс или на крайний случай бесплатный.

Нашел отличную программу на базе Eclipse - http://www.uml-lab.com, но она стоит денег, и устанавливается как проприетарный stand-alone продукт

упд: но она свалилась, набредя н внутренний класс)

Comment: сейччас попробую, спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это не совсем то, что вам нужно, но я пользовался `Enterprise Architect, standalone app`. Немного запутанный интерфейс, перегруженный функционалом :( 
Но умеет создавать диаграммы по коду и генерить код по диаграммам.